# How can I assign static IPs to strongSwan clients based on their certificates?

Tags: strongswan

I would like to assign a static IP to each client based on its certificate (using `eap-tls`).

Currently, IP is assigned dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options to assign static [virtual IP addresses](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/VirtualIp#Responder-Configuration):

- If the authentication is done via RADIUS, it's possible [to assign virtual IPs and other attributes](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/EapRadius#RADIUS-attribute-forwarding) to the clients as well. For virtual IPs that's done via  *Framed-IP[v6]-Address* RADIUS attributes.
- The [attr-sql plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Attrsql) optionally maps identities to static address leases (configurable via [ipsec pool](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IpsecPool) utility).
- The [dhcp plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/DHCPPlugin) may be used if *charon.plugins.dhcp.identity_lease* is enabled and static leases are configured on the corresponding DHCP server for the clients. The mapping can be done via client identity DHCP option (sent since 5.6.3) or via the virtual MAC addresses that's based on a hash of the client identity.
- Configure individual connection entries with single IP address pools and static remote identities so they are matched against the identities of the clients. To do that with EAP authentication is currently not straight forward, though (see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/908194/95913)).

Comment: Newbie question... coudn’t I used something in the likes of `10.0.2.2: RSA moonKey.pem`. https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Ipsecsecrets

Comment: The secrets have nothing to do with the configuration attributes. And the values before the colon are identities, which could be IP addresses, but a virtual IP assigned by the server will never be used as identity. Plus, for private keys you usually don't configure any identities, as these are only relevant locally.

Comment: Is there a sample in the docs that I can follow to setup the DHCP plugin?

Comment: The [documentation of the _dhcp_ plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/DHCPPlugin) describes how it's configured. The configuration of the DHCP server depends on the actual product. The only examples are the test scenarios that use ISC's _dhcpd_ e.g. [swanctl/dhcp-dynamic](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/swanctl/dhcp-dynamic/), [ikev2/static-client-id](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/dhcp-static-client-id/), or [ikev2/dhcp-static-mac](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/dhcp-static-mac/).

Answer (score 0):

Most flexible way to do it is usage of RADIUS server. Detailed example of configuration you can find in [the wiki of strongswan](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/EapRadius)

Comment: Could I used `/etc/ipsec.secrets`? https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Ipsecsecrets

Comment: Do you know which iptable rules I need to setup on the clients? I used the following on the server. https://medium.com/@sunknudsen/self-host-your-very-own-strongswan-ikev2-ipsec-state-of-the-art-vpn-server-for-ios-and-macos-8cd7023497fc#203e

Comment: For clients the rules are same: you should allow the esp/ah ip protocols for data transfer, and udp/4500 and udp/500 for IKE.

Comment: Guess the rules have to be inverted right? Have time to suggest client iptables rules based on my Medium story?

Comment: Created a separate question for client iptables rules. https://serverfault.com/questions/967386/what-iptable-rules-do-i-need-for-strongswan-clients