# What iptables rules do I need for strongSwan clients?

Tags: strongswan

I use the following rules on the server:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport  500 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in  --proto esp -s 10.0.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d 10.0.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.2.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s 10.0.2.0/24 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
```

What's the equivalent for the client?

Comment: How restrictive is the client's firewall configured? Because commonly any outbound traffic and related inbound traffic is allowed.

Comment: Very restricted as they are headless servers... only what’s needed in or out is allowed. Everything else is dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming related inbound traffic is allowed, for instance, with a rule like this:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If outbound traffic is generally blocked, you need to add rules to allow the following type of traffic, depending on the actual configuration:

- IKE (UDP ports 500 and 4500, by default):

  ```
  # iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
  # iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
  ```

  You could limit this more e.g. make it specific to an interface (`-o <name>`) or a destination address (`-d <ip>`). The source ports could also be matched, but in some situations using arbitrary source ports (i.e. configure `0` as source port in the strongSwan configuration) might be preferred, or are even required (e.g. if a [custom server port](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/NATTraversal#Custom-Server-Ports) is used).
- If CRLs must be downloaded, or the server certificate is verified via Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP), the appropriate TCP ports must also be allowed, for instance:

  ```
  # iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d <CRL server IP> -j ACCEPT
  # iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport <OCSP port> -d <OCSP server IP> -j ACCEPT
  ```
- If the client is behind a NAT or UDP encapsulation is forced, the ESP traffic will be sent using IKE's NAT-T UDP port. Otherwise, ESP traffic has to be allowed explicitly:

  ```
  # iptables -A OUTPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
  ```

  Again, this could be restrained to a specific destination etc.
- Additional rules will be required for the actual VPN traffic. This can either be done using strongSwan's default [updown script](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Updown), which automatically inserts rules for the negotiated traffic selectors, or with a global catch-all rule for traffic that matches any IPsec policy:

  ```
  # iptables -A OUTPUT -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
  ```

Comment: Thanks @ecdsa. That got things moving. Do you know why the client traffic isn’t routed through the VPN? Running `curl https://checkip.amazonaws.com` returns client public IP. Also, can’t SSH to client from server. Created a separate question for these issues here: https://serverfault.com/questions/968613/how-can-i-route-all-traffic-through-strongswan-vpn.